# IOS storyboard - show different views on selection of table cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

i am new to ios programming. I have multiple  view controllers. i am showing the tableView Controller first and there is a navigation controller before it .. i want to show the specific view controller depending on  the cell selected.. i have set tableView Controller to **dynamic** and **prototype Cell** to 1 
and i have segue which connected from table to my one of view controller name **APP1ViewController**  i have another two controllers name APP2 and APP3 .. how can i connect them so that on the specific cell specific view controller loads. 
here is the code of displaying cells .. at the moment there is one section and three rows in my table

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"AppCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    switch (indexPath.row)
    {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"APP 1 ";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Detail of App 1...";
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"App2";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Detail of App 2 app...";
            break;
        case 2:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"App3";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text =
            @"Detail of App 3...";
            break;

        default:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Unkown";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Unknown";
            break;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create your three segues from the controller that has the table rather than from the table or the cell itself.  Give each segue a unique identifier.  In `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, call the table view controller's `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` method and select the identifier that matches the chosen row.

Comment: yeah thanks i got it. i followed your steps now i want to ask one thing how can i show the controller after finding the segue identifier .. is that correct ?             - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
      if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"App1"] )
    {
        
        App1ViewController *app1 = segue.destinationViewController;
       
    } is that correct?

Comment: i did this  - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender { if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"App1"] ) { [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"App1" sender: self]; } but it isn't working

Comment: As I said, put the `performSegueWithIdentifier...` in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.  `prepareForSegue...` gets called **after** the segue has been triggered.

Comment: can you please edit my code .. i am new to ios. i feel difficult to understand this

Answer (score 5):

Try this,

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"your storyboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController = nil;      
    switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
       viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController1"];
        break;
    case 1:
        viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController2"];
        break;
    case 2:
        viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController3"];
        break;

    default:
        viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController4"];
        break;
     }
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: thankyou for your answer.at the moment i am trying to use the Phillip Mills way to handle it.. hope it works ..other wise i will use yours

Answer (score 1):

Implement One of Tablview's delegate method

```
tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
```

and on the above delegate method you can fetch particular view controller form your storyboard and instantiate and push to your navigation's controller as follows

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"your storyboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Your Storyboard's identifier that you want to push"];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```